# jQuery onclick method doesn't work twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, e-commerce

I have 2 onclick methods. The first one works fine but the second one doesn't works if i click first one, I need to refresh the page to run. Even if I do that, it only works once.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cart_add").on('click','.add_cart',function(){
        var product_id = $(this).data("productid");
        var size = $('ul#size').find('li.active a').data('value');
        var qty = $('.qty-input').val();
        var price = $('.special-price').data('price');
        var name = $('h1.product-name').text();
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $.post(url,{product_id:product_id,product_size:size,product_name:name,product_price:price,product_qty:qty},function(response){
            $(".variant-1").html(response);
        });
    });

    $(".secondary").on('click','.delete',function(){
        var product_id = $(this).data("id");
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $.post(url,{product_id:product_id},function(response){
            $(".variant-1").html(response);
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: console errors? also please make your question as MVCE as possible https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it will increase the likelihood of you getting a proper response.

Comment: There is no console error. Everything looks right.

Comment: did you check if there were errors just on page load, or by trying to replicate the issue?

Comment: when i try 2-3 times. ı got error. Uncaught ReferenceError: iziToast is not defined. but i didnt find how can i fix this

Comment: well it appears you are attempting somewhere in your related js (not shown above) to call iziToast and it hasn't been included in the page.

Comment: I don't think it's about iziToast I removed all the alert and result same :/

Comment: console errors just don't appear for unrelated reasons...

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.delete'

Comment: thanks that works for me. But i dont understand cause ı use same method for add_cart it works fine. Is it about render page?

Comment: Which one.........

Comment: i wonder if its because the very "formatting issue" that the editor fixed. could it be misplaced brackets? check to make sure in your og question everything is within the document ready `});`

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.delete' this works for me. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#CheckClick").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="CheckClick">button</button>
```

Take ID Instead of Class check in side your code
or take your script inside function and call it on button click

```js
function myFunction(){
   alert("it's work well")
}
```

```html
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="myFunction();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using onclick event from  html button like`

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert('"hello"');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

e`